# Relation between rows ranking

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping, joi

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

If there is any relationship between the imported and section then they should be grouped together. Depending on the relationship they should be grouped as 1,2,3,4,....

I tried a query that looks like this:

```
    select sec.section,sec.id, sec.imported, sec.id,
    case when imp.imported = sec.section or imp.imported is null then 1 ELSE 
    2  end  as rn
    from
  ( select section, id, imported from temp1) sec
    left outer join 
    (
    select imported, Section from temp1
    ) imp on imp.imported = sec.section
```

But in this scenario my rn is always 1. Can you help me review this query?
I'm not sure how to go around this. Do we need to use a while loop and do it or can this be done using a query?

Example creation script:

```
    create table temp1 (
    id int, imported int, section int, rn int, checked int default 0
    );
    insert into temp1(id, section, rn)           values (204, 718, 0);
    insert into temp1(id, imported, section, rn) values (997,718,034,0);
    insert into temp1(id, imported, section, rn) values (998,034,055,0);
    insert into temp1(id, imported, section, rn) values (111,453,234,0);
    insert into temp1(id, section, rn) values (908, 453,0);
    insert into temp1(id, imported, section, rn) values (231,234,890,0);
    insert into temp1(id, section, rn) values (342, 567,0);
```

My End Result should look like:

[image]

I'have tried with while loop too creating a stored procedure:

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_recursiveimport;
    Delimiter $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE sp_recursiveimport()  -- (IN rnX integer)
    BEGIN
    DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;   DECLARE i,j,k INT DEFAULT 0;    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp1 INTO n;
    SET i=0; set @rn = 1; --  set @k = 0;
    WHILE i<n DO 
    set j = 0; select i;
      set @sec = (select ifnull(section,0) FROM temp1 LIMIT i,1);          
      set @imp = (select ifnull(imported,0) FROM temp1 LIMIT i,1); select @imp, @sec;
        update1: while j<n do   select j;
    --         if j=0 then
               if (select ifnull(imported,0) from temp1 limit j,1) = @sec and (select checked from temp1 limit j,1) = 0 then 
               set @update  = concat('update temp1 set rn = 1, checked = 1 where imported = ',@sec); select @update;    PREPARE stmt_name FROM @update;     EXECUTE Stmt_name;     DEALLOCATE prepare stmt_name;
               set @update1 = concat('update temp1 set rn = 1, checked = 1 where section = ',@sec); select @update1;   PREPARE stmt_name FROM @update1;     EXECUTE Stmt_name;     DEALLOCATE prepare stmt_name;
               set k = j;
               end if;
               if (select ifnull(section,0)          from temp1 limit j,1) = @imp and (select checked from temp1 limit j,1) = 0 then 
               set @update3 = concat('update temp1 set rn = 1, checked = 1 where section = ',@imp);  select @update3;    PREPARE stmt_name FROM @update3;     EXECUTE Stmt_name;     DEALLOCATE prepare stmt_name;
               set @update4 = concat('update temp1 set rn = 1, checked = 1 where imported = ',@imp); select @update4;    PREPARE stmt_name FROM @update4;     EXECUTE Stmt_name;     DEALLOCATE prepare stmt_name;
               set k = j;
               end if;

    --            set @sec = (select ifnull(imported,0) from temp1 limit k,1);
    --            set @imp = (select ifnull(section,0)          from temp1 limit k,1); select @sec, @imp;
        set j= j+1;
        end while update1;

      set i = i + 1;
    END WHILE;
    END;
    $$
    delimiter;
```

Not sure why its not working.

Comment: It can be done in MySQL 8.0, but not in MySQL 5.x. Which one do you have?

Comment: I do not have 8.0. I'm on 5.7

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question since, honestly, I don't know how to write this query in MySQL 5.x.

Anyway, at least I wanted to document the answer using recursive CTEs, available on MySQL 8.0 or newer. Here it is:

```
with recursive sect as (
  select id, imported, section, row_number() over() as rn
    from temp1 where imported is null
  union all
  select t.id, t.imported, t.section, s.rn
    from temp1 t
    join sect s on t.imported = s.section
)
select * from sect order by rn;
```

Result:

```
id   imported  section  rn
---  --------  -------  --
998  34        55       1
204  <null>    718      1
997  718       34       1
231  234       890      2
908  <null>    453      2
111  453       234      2
342  <null>    567      3
```

Comment: mysql doesnot support CTEs and ranking functions also not available

Comment: do you think we can do this without using cte and window functions?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I wish I knew, but the natural solution to this query requires iterations.